# A windows API program on random ractangles...I don't know how the variable get its value

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, api, mfc

```
<pre>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<process.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);
HWND hwnd;
int clientx,clienty;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,PSTR szCmdLine,int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[]=TEXT("hello");
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;

    wndclass.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.hInstance=hInstance;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra=0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra=0;
    wndclass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc=WndProc;
    wndclass.lpszClassName=szAppName;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName=NULL;

    if(!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,TEXT("this program requires windows NT"),TEXT("wrong"),MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd=CreateWindow(szAppName,TEXT("random rectangles"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100,100,800,600,
        NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd,iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

VOID Thread(PVOID pvoid)
{
    HBRUSH hbrush;
    HDC hdc;
    int xleft,xright,ytop,ybottom,ired,igreen,iblue;
    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(clientx!=0||clienty!=0)
        {
            xleft=rand()%clientx;
            xright=rand()%clientx;
            ytop=rand()%clienty;
            ybottom=rand()%clienty;
            ired=rand()%255;
            igreen=rand()%255;
            iblue=rand()%255;

            hdc=GetDC(hwnd);
            hbrush=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(ired,igreen,iblue));
            SelectObject(hdc,hbrush);

            Rectangle(hdc,min(xleft,xright),min(ytop,ybottom),max(xleft,xright),max(ytop,ybottom));
            ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
            DeleteObject(hbrush);
        }
    }//while
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        _beginthread(Thread,0,NULL);
        return 0;
    case WM_SIZE:
        clientx=LOWORD(lParam);
        clienty=HIWORD(lParam);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam);
}
<code>
```

I do not know how the variable clientx and clienty at the top of the program get their value s when the program runs...Because I didn't see any value assignments in the program ....I used to debug it in my visual studio 2010, when it ran to "ShowWindow(hwnd,iCmdShow);"in the WinMain(),the clientx and clienty got their values (735 and 654 random...).But before that the clientx and clienty both were "0". I was confused~~ Thanks a lot~~~ :)

Comment: Have you checked what happens when you get a `WM_SIZE` message? Looks like assignment to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you are asking why `clientx` and `clienty` both have value zero when they are not explicitly initialised to zero.

A global variable, as `clientx` and `clienty`, has static storage duration. If a variable with static storage duration is not explicitly initialised (from section *6.7.8 Initialization* of C99 standard):

- if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
- **if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;**
- if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
- if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
  rules.

Answer (score 0):

Client x and and client y are initialised to zero (as mentioned by hmjd) as they are global.

When the application opens Windows sends a WM_RESIZE message to the window procedure to tell it how big the window is (and this message is sent again if the user resizes the window). Near the bottom you can see the code where the clientx and clienty are set according to the parameters of the RESIZE message - essentially they are the height and width of the client window in pixels.

Answer (score -1):

These values comes from your previous session. When you close your top-level window, Windows remembers its size and location.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235994

> Windows saves size and location information for closed windows in the
>   following registry location: 
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams
>
> **Windows saves size and location information for up to 28 different
>   windows.** Each window's size and location parameters are stored in a
>   subkey of the Streams key.